# How to guard existing variable assignment without let/var in Swift 2

Tags: variables, swift2

The `guard` keyword is awesome and I've been using it ever since Swift 2 rolled out. I was able to use it successfully in many scenarios, including this one:

```
for viewController in self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
    guard let myCustomVC = viewController as? MyCustomViewController else {continue}

    myCustomVC.doWhatItHasToDo()
    break
}
```

Works like a charm. Iterates over all `viewControllers` in current `navigationController` until it finds the one I want.

**The problem** is: now I need update the code above to reuse `myCustomVC` variable outside the `for..in` scope. It should be as simple as declaring the variable before the scope, but I can't find a way to `guard` variable assignment without `let` or `var` keywords.

The following **hypothetical** code demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve, but Swift won't let me do so:

```
var myCustomVC: MyCustomViewController
for viewController in self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
    guard myCustomVC = viewController as? MyCustomViewController else {continue}

    myCustomVC.doWhatItHasToDo()
    break
}

// Now myCustomVC is available outside the for...in scope
myCustomVC.doWhatever()
```

Xcode suggests using `==` instead of `=` as it expects the `guard` statement to be a boolean context instead of a variable assignment.

[image: Xcode error]

Any ideas on how to work around this issue?

Comment: Can you just use filter to find the controller you want?

Comment: let myCustomVC = viewControllers.filter { /* put predicate here */ }.first; myCustomVC.doWhatItHasToDo(); myCustomVC.doWhatever();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon me for not answering your question. I don't think what you are asking is possible. But I have an alternative.

It seems like you are manually writing the `filter` method over and over again. I'd suggest just using `filter` to find the element(s) you want. If more than one match, then use `first` to take the first one. For example, below I select the first even number from a list:

```
let myArray = [0,1,3,5,7,4,6,10,11]
let myNum = myArray.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }.first
```

I don't know the exact syntax to use for your predicate but something like the following

```
let myCustomVC = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.filter {
    $0 is MyCustomViewController }.first

// myCustomVC will be an optional because first returns an optional
if let myCustomVC = myCustomVC {
    myCustomVC.doWhatItHasToDo()
    myCustomVC.doWhatever()
}
```

Or if you have an action to perform on each element that matches the predicate then use `foreach`

```
    let myCustomVC = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.filter {
    $0 is MyCustomViewController }.foreach { // action // }
```

Comment: Super answer Michael! Thanks for the detailed explanation and awesome examples. Indeed I was _reinventing the wheel_ without realising it.

Comment: Cool. Glad this meets your needs

Answer (score 1):

I continued to think about your question. It is possible to do what you originally asked, however the solution I came up with is a little convoluted. Basically it involves defining a closure of type `Any -> Bool` which you can use in your guard statement. Here's a complete example. Perhaps if this is useful you could clean it up some what. The actual `for` loop is not bad, assuming you already had your predicate closure defined somewhere.

```
class MyClass {}

var myCollection = [Any]()
// add sample elements 
myCollection.append("hello")
myCollection.append(MyClass())

// declare the variable to receive the "found" element
var myElement:MyClass? = nil

// define our predicate to use in guard statement
let myPredicate:Any->Bool = { obj in
    if let obj = obj as? MyClass {
        myElement = obj
        return true
    }
    return false
}

for v in myCollection {
    guard myPredicate(v)
    else {continue}

   // do something with v
}

if let myElement = myElement {
    print(myElement)
}
```

UPDATE: A much simpler example (it still requires the let)

```
for v in myCollection {
    guard let myObj = v as? MyClass else {continue}
    myElement = myObj
}
```